# Probability of getting a specific Tetris piece given previous pieces

Tags: bayesian, proportion, uniform-distribution

I'm doing a small reinforcement learning project involving Tetris, just for fun.

Considering that each piece has a constant probability of being selected, how can I calculate the probability of receiving a *specified next piece*, given the record of the previous spawned pieces? (maybe the piece sequence is not independent as I'm using computer-generated random numbers?)

My idea is simple:  I would like to 'watch' the 'S', 'Z' and 'I' pieces distributions and somehow incorporate those numbers on the players policy, because are key pieces, so i think it would make a difference on the average performance.

Any ideas on how I can incorporate the variables?
Thanks!

Comment: I thought they would be independent of the history, are they not?

Comment: Correct with respect to what? Describing the original implementation of the game? Generally speaking, I would expect like @Memming that independently drawing a random piece based on some fixed probability would be fine but anything is possible really and your description is not very clear. Is there some implicit underlying question or are you genuinely interested in the game of Tetris?

Comment: I suspect you've fallen victim to one of the classic blunders; no, not starting a land war in Asia, but the [gambler's fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy).

Comment: Your description seems self-contradictory: If the probability is constant, then the choices must be independent. There is no reason to assume that a piece that did not come yet is more likely to come next. Quite the contrary: Intuitively, from a simple Bayesian perspective, with every “negative” trial, your estimate of the (constant but unknown) probability for this particular piece to be drawn should go down.

Comment: What about the pseudo random generator? is it really wrong to assume that a piece that did not come yet is more likely to show next, in this case?

Comment: Now we are getting into the intricacies of the implementation, I would hope it is wrong, yes, but I really don't know. It seems you really wish it to be that way even if it seems unlikely in this context but I still see no reason to assume it is generally the case. In most cases, I would expect games (lottery, casino games, dice games, computer games…) to be designed with stable probabilities and random draws (hence the gambler's fallacy) but I guess you could assume otherwise to create an abstract probability problem or even code a Tetris with some dependency if you wanted to…

Comment: Did you program this? Or are you measuring probabilities of _some preexisting version of Tetris_? Which version? It's possible the pieces are chosen in a (complex) deterministic fashion, with uniform probabilities, or with dependent probabilities. Why would you expect someone to know how some unspecified version of Tetris was implemented?

Comment: No, it's the standard version. I just read some papers that incorporated those aspects in the final model, and they got good results. I'm trying to find the links to post here.

Comment: @Fernando can you point us to these papers? I don't see how pseudo-random number generators can be exploited unless they are really really bad ones.

Comment: @Fernando What is the "standard" version? There are _literally thousands of versions_, including dozens from the official publisher.

Comment: http://paul.rutgers.edu/~babes/RL2009Tetris.pdf

Comment: @Fernando I had a quick look at the paper, the Tetris environment the authors consider was deliberately developed to be “adversarial” and they explicitly do *not* assume a fixed probability of getting a given piece. They also suggest that the piece you get depends on the state of the board (what you need to fill the gaps) and not directly on the record of previous pieces (i.e. no balancing out frequent pieces as you initially hypothesized).

Comment: Given all that, it seems impossible to compute an explicit probability as everything is in principle possible (which is the point, apparently)… It's also not very meaningful to ask about Tetris in general so if you cannot make the question more specific I am inclined to ask to close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to the question as stated (as of writing):

> Considering that each piece has a constant probability of being selected, how can I calculate the probability of receiving a specified next piece, given the record of the previous spawned pieces?

Your best guess regarding the probability is simply the observed probability up to that point (i.e. the proportions of previously spawned pieces represented by each piece). Since you assume it is constant, it should converge to the true value as you get more data.

If you are concerned about oscillations and extreme estimates at the beginning of the game (when you don't have much data), you could perhaps consider some sort of Bayesian approach.

At the same time, the ideas about dependency, balancing out, etc. you expressed in the comments and other parts of the question contradict this problem statement as they would imply that the probability to get a given piece is *not* constant. If that's the case, anything is possible and you would need to be more specific about what you are willing to assume and what you are looking for.